# Scrapy infinite loop

Tags: python, scrapy

Infinite crawling problem with scrapy

On `example.com/one` there is a relative link to `second/third` which leads to `example.com/one/second/third`. If `example.com/one/second/third` also has a relative link to `second/one`, there is an infinite loop (`example.com/one/second/third/second/third/second/third/..../second/third`). The only way I found to stop this kind of behavior is to limit the DEPTH_LIMIT. 
However, this has the drawback of limiting very long "next page" structures... Do you know of another way to prevent this infinite loop without limiting the DEPTH_LIMIT?

Edit:
The spider uses a simple linkextractor to follow links:
`self.linkextractor = LinkExtractor(allow_domains=[urlparse(url).netloc])`

Comment: What is the code that you have used?

Comment: The spider follows a simple link extractor: `self.linkextractor = LinkExtractor(allow_domains=[urlparse(url).netloc])`